# Regex to find a word after a specific word and before a specific character

Tags: regex, regex-group, impala, regexp-replace

I am trying to pull the word that comes after "allignment=" pattern and before the next semi-colon occurance.
I only want the first match in the text.

An example text sample:

"*Testing all parameters. allignment=gate; Seach all the gateways. allignment=block; Search all the blocks*"

Desired output: **gate**

Note: This is for executing in Impala Database, which does not support look around assertions. I tried regex (?<=allignment=)(\w+[^;]) which seems to work in regex testers, but Impala does not support it because it is a look back assertion.
Pls help building the required regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impala may not support lookarounds but it allows you to extract matching groups according to [this documentation](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/impala_string_functions.html#string_functions__regexp_extract) (I hope I'm looking at the right thing).

So you can use

```
allignment=(\w+);
```

and select the first matching group.

Looks like the syntax would be:

```
regexp_extract(<text to search>, 'allignment=(\w+);', 1)
```